# Run code before any django management command

Tags: django

With middleware, I can execute code at the beginning and end of each HTTP request.

With Celery tasks I can accomplish the same by using the `task_prerun` and `task_postrun` signals.

What about django management commands? Is it possible to have code that runs at the beginning (and possibly end) of each django management command? Such code must also know which django management command is about to run (or has finished running). There is a ticket about a [signal on application startup](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13024) which may or may not do what I want, but it's not ready anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly state there's no specific place in Django where you can put code that is executed at every startup...

There are some places that you might be able to 'misuse' for this purpose, eg. code in `urls.py` or in the `models.py` should be run on startup...(eg. the admin uses this circumstances for its `admin.autodiscover()` in `urls.py`).

There are also some possibilities to find out if the code is being run due to the execution of a management command; you could plainly check the command line arguments via [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) if they contain any management commands. Another possibilty would be to specify different settings for running the app via server/management command....

Comment: This was my thought, too. Another less-than-completely-clean approach would be to MonkeyPatch django.core.management.base.py, specifically `BaseCommand.execute()`, and put a wrapper around it.

Comment: Well if you like monkey-patching sure... What would you like to achieve in the first place?

Comment: Well, for one thing, I'd like my monkey to stop crashing while I'm playing WoW. :-)

Comment: I also had this idea: You put the startup code in, say, `startup.py`, and in `settings.py` you `import startup`. I tested it and it seems to work. It may be cleaner in certain cases (e.g. you could add some system-administration-related stuff to an existing Django application without changing the application's code).

Answer (score 1):

If the code you need to add before/after management command doesn't require access to django models/settings then u can simply update `manage.py` script.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
from startup import pre_management_command, post_management_command

pre_management_command(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:])
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
post_management_command(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2:])
```

I am not 100% sure but I suppose `post_management_command` would have access to django models.

This is just basic example, In reality u will need to ensure that `sys.argv` has at least two entries and that the second entry doesn't start with `-` to prevent false positive calls like

```
 ./manage.py
 ./manage.py -h
 ./manage.py --help
```