# How to track the time Django takes to run migrations?

Tags: python, sql, django, migration

I have multiple Django apps with loads of migrations, and they can take a long time to run when building on a VM. For logistic reasons, and to identify areas where we can increase speed I'd like to be able to view the time it took for all migrations to run.

What would be the preferred way of doing so? Maybe a management command that kicks off when you run `migrate`? Can't seem to find much on the topic.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822514/run-code-before-any-django-management-command   , these are no clean solutions but could be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a job for [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html).

You can write a tiny script that runs the migration while wrapping the call in `cProfile.run()`

You should also check out [SnakeViz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/). This tool helps a lot for profiling your program.